# what step and process involved in OTP & SMS-Gateway implementation

Tags: java, spring, sms, sms-gateway, one-time-password

I working on a project which is going to be used as secure money transfer application.
I am using **spring** ,**hibernate** and **jpos**. During money transfer I have to send an OTP to user's mobile from the server and in response user have to enter the **OTP**.

So my question is what processes and how many steps are involved to achieve this, I have googled as well as search on stackoverflow but failed to understand entire mechanism.I dont want to use **AT commonds** & sms should be you know send over/through http or better medium.

Please  help me to understand the entire mechanism ,the do's and dont's as now its a top priority task for me & have to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SMPP protocol to push messages to the intended recipient.
There are few open source implementation which provide smpp protocol implementation out of the box.

Have a look at [JSMPP](https://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/) or [playsms](http://playsms.org/).

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks ,but I want to know how to implement ,the mechanism & the processes involved to send messages from my standalone application as otp

Comment: Yes it needs sms-gateway.. or you have to collaborate with some third-party provider, which provide and http interface.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: JSMPP has sample code to send sms(otp in your case), but it requires you to connect to some smpp-server, may be a modem which provide smpp interface (there are many available in market)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply . you know what ,i am still not getting how to work it out, please explain me the mechanism, what-how to bundle all these things in order to achieve my task.

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk have a look at this [sample](https://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/source/browse/trunk/src/java/examples/org/jsmpp/examples/SimpleSubmitExample.java), it might give you an idea.

Comment: Ok ,i'll take a look at this example & get back to you

Comment: ok ,after using this jsmpp api, i can send sms but i need a sms-gateway, right? what kind of speed(no. of sms's per second) this will provide ,i need large volumes of sms's

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk For large volumes you can contact your local telecom operator to provide you a SMPP account, else you can contact a third-party which have an account with operator and act as a smpp-gateway, so instead of connection directly to operator, you connect to this gateway, Last option is you can use a modem, but speed and through put will be an issue here, it cannot be used for large volume of sms. Hope i answer your query. SMPP account detail you need to configure in your jsmpp client

Comment: thanks pal, one last question, jsmpp api or smpp is diffrent from smpp-gateway or smpp account provided by telecom operator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30955/discussion-between-alankar-and-arvin-codehunk)